# Different probability when getting the result

Tags: python, json, pandas, sentiment-analysis, streamlit

I have a sentiment analysis code and json here that supports multiple sentences via csv or txt

Here's the json looks like where they get the result

```
{"text_sentiment": "positive", "text_probability": [0.33917574607174916, 0.26495590980799744, 0.3958683441202534]}
```

Here's my code for single Sentence

```
single_sentence = st.text_input('Enter Sentence Below:')
if single_sentence:
    url = 'http://.com/classify/?text='+ single_sentence
    r = requests.get(url)
    result = r.json()["text_sentiment"]
    proba = r.json()["text_probability"]
    proba_rd = [i*100 for i in proba]
```

Multiple Sentence

```
multiple_sentence = st.file_uploader("Upload your file input here", type=["csv","txt"])
if multiple_sentence is not None:
    input_c = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Comments','Result'])
    for i in range(input_df.shape[0]):
        url = 'http://.com/classify/?text='+str(input_df.iloc[i])
        r = requests.get(url)
        result = r.json()["text_sentiment"]
        proba = r.json()["text_probability"]
        proba_test = [i*100 for i in proba]
        input_c = input_c.append({'Comments': input_df.loc[i].to_string(index=False),'Result': result, 'Probability': max(proba_test)}, ignore_index = True)
        input_c.set_index('Probability')
    st.write(input_c)
```

I'll use this sentence to get the result

```
"The product is one of the best out there."
```

Here's the result of when i use it in Single Sentence

```
{"text_sentiment": "positive", "text_probability": [0.17189643331103147, 0.17537792497833374, 0.6527256417106349]}
```

Here's for the multiple sentence

```
{"text_sentiment": "positive", "text_probability": [0.23948938642478806, 0.18262169847430867, 0.5778889151009032]}
```

Any idea why it's like this? both of them are getting the result on the same url/json.

I also tried changing this code in the multiple sentence

```
url = 'http://.com/classify/?text='+str(input_df.iloc[i])
```

into

```
url = 'http://.com/classify/?text='+str(input_df.loc[i].to_string)
```

and it also gave different result

Edit: nvm i fixed it
using this code

```
url = 'http://.com/classify/?text='+str(input_df.loc[i, 0])
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help?  We cannot run this code and we don't know what is going on underneath this http link....

Comment: @PaulBrennan added it

Comment: `http://.com/classify` does not really help me as I cannot see the code and why its giving a different answer - also I have no idea as to what .com is.  What service are you using, where is the code for that?

Comment: It seems to me that this is more model-related than anything. Without inspecting the model and how does it come up with predictions it is hard to pinpoint why your probabilities are different between your 2 examples.